# Call method from Class in DLL without exposing Class

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

I have a class in a DLL that has a method that I want to call externally but without exposing the class itself. Lets say I have the following class:

```
// MyClass.h
class MyClass
{
public:
    // ...
    void SetNumber(int x);
private:
    int _number;
};

// MyClass.cpp
// ...
MyClass::SetNumber(int x)
{ 
    _number = x;
}
```

I want to create an instance of MyClass and use it throughout the lifetime of the DLL.

```
// main.cpp

#define EXTERN extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )

int APIENTRY WinMain(/* ... */)
{
    MyClass * myclass = new MyClass();  // I need to use this instance
                                        // everytime in the exported SetNumber function.
    return 0;
}

void EXTERN SetNumber(int x)
{
     // Get myclass pointer
     myclass.SetNumber(x);
}
```

Right now I have two ideas and I'm not sure if either is a good approach.

1) Use a Singleton where I create a private static instance of `MyClass` and use it in every function I export by calls like `MyClass().Instance().SetNumber(x)`. Is the static instance safe from external use?

2) Create a thread when linked and have the thread respond to events that each of my exported functions would create and push into a public queue. This sounds like a major hack.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A third option is an opaque interface; e.g. a function that returns a new instance of the class cast as a `HANDLE`, and helper functions in the DLL that take the `HANDLE` as a parameter and call the class method through it (and obviously another function to free the `HANDLE`).

Comment: Being a singleton is an inherent property of a class. It does not depend on whether you want to expose its methods with particular technology. If it is inherently a singleton, go ahead and program it as a singleton. As for your second idea, it's essentially "let's make a singleton in an extremely obscure and roundabout way".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options at your disposal. I'll present here 2 options where the client of your DLL has full control of the lifetime of the `MyClass` instance that it uses, although the client doesn't know it's actually a `MyClass` instance.

Assuming your DLL-exposed feature is publicly known as *Flubber*. The first option is that you deliver your DLL with a public header file Flubber.h containing this:

```
#ifdef FLUBBER_EXPORTS
#define FLUBBER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FLUBBER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

typedef struct FlubberHandle_* FlubberHandle;

FLUBBER_API FlubberHandle CreateFlubber();
FLUBBER_API void DestroyFlubber(FlubberHandle flubber);
FLUBBER_API void SetFlubberNumber(FlubberHandle flubber, int number);
```

The implementation looks like this:

```
#include "Flubber.h"


class MyClass
{
public:
    void SetNumber(int x){ _number = x;}
private:
    int _number;
};

struct FlubberHandle_
{
    MyClass impl;
};

FLUBBER_API FlubberHandle CreateFlubber()
{
    return new FlubberHandle_;
}

FLUBBER_API void DestroyFlubber(FlubberHandle flubber)
{
    delete flubber;
}

FLUBBER_API void SetFlubberNumber(FlubberHandle flubber, int number)
{
    flubber->impl.SetNumber(number);
}
```

When you build your DLL, define the `FLUBBER_EXPORTS` macro. When the client uses the DLL, it must not do the same, but just reference the DLL import library (Flubber.lib) and include the Flubber.h header:

```
#include <Flubber.h>

int main()
{
    FlubberHandle flubberHandle = CreateFlubber();
    ... // Do lots of other stuff before setting the number
    SetFlubberNumber(flubberHandle, 4711);
    ... // Do even more stuff and eventually clean up the flubber
    DestroyFlubber(flubberHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

That's the simplest way to let the DLL client contol the lifetime of an instance that exposes certain functionality.

However, it doesn't take much effort to provide your DLL clients with a richer interface by "wrapping back" the `FlubberHandle` management in a proper RAII class. If the "hidden" `MyClass` class exposes many other public things, you can still opt to only expose what you choose in the exported free functions (`CreateFlubber`, `DestroyFlubber` and `SetFlubberNumber`) and the RAII class:

```
#ifdef FLUBBER_EXPORTS
#define FLUBBER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FLUBBER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

typedef struct FlubberHandle_* FlubberHandle;

FLUBBER_API FlubberHandle CreateFlubber();
FLUBBER_API void DestroyFlubber(FlubberHandle flubber);
FLUBBER_API void SetFlubberNumber(FlubberHandle flubber, int number);

class Flubber final
{
    FlubberHandle m_flubber;

public:

    Flubber() : m_flubber(CreateFlubber()) {}
    Flubber(const Flubber&) = delete;
    Flubber& operator=(const Flubber&) = delete;
    ~Flubber() { DestroyFlubber(m_flubber); }

    void SetNumber(int number) { SetFlubberNumber(m_flubber, number); }
};
```

Using the RAII class, the client's experience of your DLL and its API will be much improved:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <Flubber.h>

int main()
{
    Flubber flubber;
    ... // Do lots of other stuff before setting the number
    flubber.SetNumber(4711);

    return 0;
}
```

This last approach was coined "Hourglass Interface" by Stefanus DuToit (his presentation "Hourglass Interfaces for C++ APIs" at CppCon 2014 is available online at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVYdHDm0q6Y), and it's simply the idea that you have a library with a "fat"/full/rich C++ implementation in the bottom. You expose its functionality to library clients via a thin C function layer. On top of that, you also distribute a rich C++ interface to your exposed functionality by wrapping the C functions in a proper (usually RAII) wrapper class.

Comment: The RAII class is pretty slick, but the main use case for this DLL is to be used in Python and I heard exporting classes to other languages is not wise unless you can confirm the setup will be exactly the same all the time. I was expecting consumers to have to use init and cleanup functions anyway...

Comment: If you want to have 1 global instance _internally_ in the library and use that one all the time, instead of letting the client create and destroy an opaque handle type, like my example does, then you can just create it in a library `init` function and destroy it in a library `deinit` function, and then use that instance _inside_ the exposed "C" functions without the client ever seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to expose the class itself, a simple solution is to use a wrapping function taking an opaque `void *` pointer as suggested by Jonathan Potter. If you want it to be called from C code, or if you need an unmangled symbol, you can optionnally declare it with C linkage:

```
void setNumber (void *obj, int x) {
    static_cast<MyClass *>(obj)->SetNumber(x);
}
```

or:

```
extern "C" void setNumber (void *obj, int x) {
    static_cast<MyClass *>(obj)->SetNumber(x);
}
```

(BTW, it is how first C++ compilers that were just C pre-compilers translated method calls...)